# PHP Fatal error with uploading file from iphone

Tags: php, iphone, file-upload

I am trying to create a webpage to upload an image from iPhone's photo library or take an image using iPhone's camera.

[This is the error message on my iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD7DC.png)

This is the html code to upload the image

```
<html>
<form action="test_upload_image_results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <br><input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload">
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

This is the php code (test_upload_image_results.php) used to upload the image

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
print_r($_FILES);

$tmpName = $_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"];
$destDir = "uploads/";

if (!is_dir($destDir))
{
    throw new Exception('Destination is not a directory.');
}

if (!is_writable($destDir))
{
    throw new Exception('Destination directory is not writable.');
}


$destination = $destDir.basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);

if (is_file($destination))
{
    throw new Exception('Destination filename already exists.');
}



if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $destination))
{
    echo "done";
}
else
{
    throw new Exception('Unable to move file.');
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if this is a very elementary question.

Comment: [UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your php ini config `upload_max_filesize` **is lower than size of uploading image**.

Try to change `upload_max_filesize` to bigger one in php.ini

For more, see file eupload error codes at php.net doc http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Thanks for the recommended solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, there is no value set for `$imageUpload['tmp_name']` and size is 0 - the image has not been uploaded

The error `1` indicates

> "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php